# Use custom AMI for GPU on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I have a EC2 instance (ubuntu) with GPU, in this instance I have a docker image running with this gpu.
So I launch my container with --privileged
Everything is working smoothly.
However I'm unable to launch the same configuration using eb and a custom AMI.

I have tried a bunch of stuff such as http://stormerider.com/blog/2012/08/16/building-an-ubuntu-ami-with-elastic-beanstalk-support/ but I don't have any good results

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Comment: A script is launched and rpm files are downloaded. But since it's a ubuntu the rpm cannot be launched